# Green screen on RTSP streaming using vlc

Tags: android, video-streaming, rtsp, libvlc

Hi i have implemented RTSP streaming using libvlc. Am getting green screen on Qualcom based devices and the stream is working fine on Exynos and Mediatek based devices. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: It will be great if you can provide more detailed information like code or logs :)

Comment: hardware decoding problem, try disabling it

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @mfkl. Your comment worked for me.

**From VLC player:**

- Click `Tools`
- `Preferences`
- `Input/Codecs`
- Select `Disable` from dropdown

[image]